# Uncaught TypeError when trying to use window.onLoad() in js script in HTML page

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make a button for my site that will copy my discord to the users clipboard. Before coding it into my site, I tried it out on JSFiddle, where it worked perfectly. However, when I run the page on my PC, I get the following error in the console:
`copyText.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onclick' of null at window.onload (copyText.js:2) window.onload @ copyText.js:2 load (async) (anonymous) @ copyText.js:1`

The code for my HTML page is as followings:
`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

    <head>
    
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>pinkflamey.nl :)</title>
        <link rel="icon" href="icon.png">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/navigation.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/base.css">
        
    </head>
    
    <body>
    
        <h1 class="title">pinkflameinthepan's website!!</h1>
        <br>

        <div class="topnav">
            <a href="index.html">Home</a>
            <a href="blog/blog.html">Blog</a>
            <a class="active "href="contact.html">Contact</a>
            <a href="about.html">About</a>
        </div>
    
        <h1>Contact</h1>
        <br>
        <br>
        <h3>Discord</h3>
        <div>
            <button id="copy" value="pinkflameinthepan#2989" class="copybutton">
                <input type="image" src="images/discord.png">
                <script src="scripts/copyText.js"></script>
            </button>
        </div>
    
    </body>
    
</html>
```

`

And my js is:
`

```
window.onload = function(){
    document.getElementById('test!!!').onclick = function(){
        const text = document.getElementById("test!!!").value;
            console.log(text);
            navigator.clipboard.writeText(text).then(() => {
                alert('Text copied to clipboard');
            }).catch(err => {
                alert('Error in copying text: ', err);
            });
    }
}
```

`

I tried finding solutions online but with no success. I tried putting the script inside of the HTML page instead of a separate .js file, and moving that to before and after the `<button>` and to the start of the page, but this did not work.

I hope someone can help me find a solution!!

Comment: Do you want to copy the file itself?
And then it will allow the user to paste wherever he wants.
If so, for security reasons you cannot copy the files in the buffer.

Answer (score 1):

I think you meant:

```
document.getElementById('copy').onclick = function(){
```

Comment: getElementById('copy')

Comment: oh my god im so stupid, i forgot to change it- thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```js
document.getElementById('test!!!').onclick
```

is throwing an error:

```
TypeError: Cannot set property 'onclick' of null
```

because there is no HTML element with the id of 'test!!!'.

To fix the error, change that line to:

```js
document.getElementById('copy').onclick
```

Comment: oh my god im so stupid, i forgot to change it- thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

There is no element on the document with an ID of "test!!!". This makes `document.getElementById('test!!!')` return `null` which is why you're getting the error. If you're trying to handle the click on your button, you should use:

```js
document.getElementById('copy').onclick = function(){
    ...
}
```

Comment: oh my god im so stupid, i forgot to change it- thank you!!